# JS - How do I set this script to be applied to multiple class instances?

Tags: jquery, multiple-instances

I was given the following script so that it applies a function to all the elements that have the class .cloudzoom. It works, but only for the first element. I see that there's something to be done with the each() function but I am not that well familiar with scripting (yet).

```
         (function($){
            // When mouse leaves browser...
            $(document).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                // Get the Cloud Zoom instance and close zoom window.
                var cz = $('.cloudzoom').data('CloudZoom');
                cz.closeZoom();
            });
        })(jQuery);
```

Any help? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   (function($){
        // When mouse leaves browser...
        $(document).bind('mouseleave',function(){
            // Get the Cloud Zoom instance and close zoom window.
            $('.cloudzoom').each(function(){
               $(this).data('CloudZoom').closeZoom();
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: YAY! This one works! :) Thanks for your time and effort! both of the above that answered!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     (function($){
        // When mouse leaves browser...
        $(document).bind('mouseleave',function(){
            // Get the Cloud Zoom instances and close their zoom windows.
            $('.cloudzoom').each(function() {
                $(this).data('CloudZoom').closeZoom();
            })
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Whoops. I forgot a bracket there. Sorry.